# Adb root works but adb shell su does not

Tags: android, android-wifi, adb

I'm trying to communicate with my xperia z3c device from adb, no touch, no display, no usb debugging.
Only way a can do something is via adb in recovery mode. OS installed is lineage 17 but it is reset to factory. I'm tryint to activate wifi to mirror the phone via wifi and configure it. For that I need root access to shell. The device seems to be rooted:

```
C:\..\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
BY900FCQ1Z      recovery
C:\..\platform-tools>adb root
adbd is already running as root
```

But when I enter in shell no command is working:

```
C:\...\platform-tools>adb shell
z3c:/ # svc wifi enable
/sbin/sh: svc: not found
z3c:/ # su
/sbin/sh: su: not found
127|z3c:/ #
```

There is a way so solve this?
Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: honestly not sure if your question belongs here, or maybe instead [here](https://android.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Is there a way to move there?

Comment: not that i know of, but you can just post your question there like you would here. just make sure you read to see if it would be on-topic there

Comment: For what you need `su` when already being `root`?

Comment: `su` was only a test to see if the device is rooted. I need to use `svc`, `am`... commands but no one of these is working. It seams device not rooted.

Comment: I found this reply that help me undestand why I have rooted my device but shell commands are not working: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/96736/difference-between-installing-supersu-using-play-store-versus-a-custom-recovery I need to install `su` binaries in the device.